# problema en subir un archivo a un servidor utilizando expo react-native y axios, el backend esta hecho en node.js

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo

Al querer subir un archivo en mi servidor utilizando el endpoint correspondiente me sale "Network Error ", que podría ser?. Me podrían ayudar por favor, la verdad he intentado mucho, y a veces el error me indica que no sube ningún archivo.

Esta es mi configuración de axios

```
import axios from 'axios';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const baseURL = 'https://apiacademica.nousproyect.com/api';

const ilustroApi = axios.create({ baseURL });

ilustroApi.interceptors.request.use(
    async(config) => {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
        if ( token ) {
            config.headers['x-token'] = token;
        }
        return config;
    }
);
export default ilustroApi;
```

Esta es mi función que utilizo para subir el archivo:

```
 const pickDocument = async () => {
        const dataFile: DocumentPicker.DocumentResult = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({ type: "*/*", copyToCacheDirectory: false })
        if (dataFile.type == 'success') {
            const upfile: any = {
                name: dataFile.name,
                type: 'image/jpeg',
                uri: dataFile.uri,

            }
            const data = new FormData();
            data.append('archivo', upfile)
            console.log(data)
            setFileName(dataFile.name);
            try {
                const res = await ilustroApi.post("/uploads/fileTeacher", data);
                console.log('..............');
                console.log(res.data);
            } catch (ex) {
                console.log('xxxxxxxxx')
                console.log(ex);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Intenta en el catch agregar un console log de ex.response, ex.request y ex.message eso te podría dar mas información acerca del error.

Comment: Pudiste solucionarlo, tengo un problema parecido, lo subo a producción y no me deja hacer ninguna petición